# Reverse Relationships

Tags: relations

Doing my first Craft job and stuck with a reverse related entries thing. 
I’ve got a channel of “Sectors” and a channel of “News”. The entries in news have a relationship field back to the “Sectors”.
When I’m viewing a “Sector” entry, I want to show links to entries in News that have a relationship to it.

I’ve tried a few things but essentially I’ve got this…

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="panel">
    <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>

    {{ entry.body }}
    </div>

    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(entry) %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But, even though I have a news entry related to a specific Sector entry, the above code doesn't show any related entries.

Oddly, if I do this...

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(entry) %}
```

Then I get some output but it shows me something from a different channel.

I’m confused. Can someone help?

**Update**

Schoolboy error alert!

I had the wrong field in my news entries. There was a category field set up which had the same values as the sector names. Once I'd replaced the field with the proper one it all worked as expected!

Comment: You are reassigning the value of the `entry` variable in your `for` loop. What happens when you change the `for` loop to: `{% for relatedEntry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(entry) %}`. Then output `{{ relatedEntry.title }}`.

Comment: I thought that was the problem (and it may have been an issue). But I found the real problem. Stupid error on my part. I'll update my question to explain.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, @foamcow.  Can you add your update as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schoolboy error alert!

I had the wrong field in my news entries. There was a category field set up which had the same values as the sector names. Once I'd replaced the field with the proper one it all worked as expected!