# How many levels will RelatedTo work? In Reverse?

Tags: relations, entries-field, relatedto, relationships

The TL;DR summary: if I have a related Entries field that I access, can I then access an Entries field within that entry?

I created a learning project running on MAMP to help me learn Craft, and one of the things I'm trying to wrap my head around is some of the ways I can use Relationships. [Originally I had a Matrix field but I deleted that because it was adding too much complexity](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/cant-get-a-simple-reverse-relations-for-entries-field-to-work).

I picked the NFL draft as a data set because it's easily available and has many different cross relationships.

The basic concept is this, you have 32 NFL teams, which have their own channel `nflTeams` (not singles, regular channel), a channel for the players that are available (`draftClass2021`), a channel for the schools the players attended (`colleges`), and finally a channel for that years Draft (`nflDraft2021`).

None of my sections are singles, everything is a regular channel.

Within that Sections structure I would have 2 Entries fields in the `nflDraft2021` section:

`draftPick` (the player selected, from section `draftClass2021`)
`teamDraftedby` (the team that selected him, from section `nflTeams`)

Each entry in the `draftClass2021` would also have an Entries field `playersSchool`, which links to the `colleges` section.

What I am trying to figure out is, using reverse relationships, can I have a page for each NFL team that lists all the players they selected in the draft, AND the school each attended?

I can get the first part, the players selected, and I can even pull the data from other fields in that related entry, but not the Entries field that links to the school.

I created a graphic to help visualize the structure:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
{% set myEntryQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('nflTeams')
    .all() %}

{# title for team page #}   
<h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>

{# get the related entries from the nflDraft2021 channel #}
{% set players = craft.entries.section('nflDraft2021').relatedTo(entry).all() %}

{% for player in players %}


  {% set relatedEntries = player.draftPick.all() %}


  {% if relatedEntries|length %}
      <ul>
          {% for rel in relatedEntries %}
              <li>{{ player.draftSlot }} <a href="{{ rel.url }}">{{ rel.title }}</a> <br>{{rel.combineOrProDay }} 
             {{ rel.playerPosition }} <br> 
             
             {# This is the Entries field that is related to the player #}
             {{ rel.playersSchool }}
              </li>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I've read the documentation on Relationships and Entries fields but I couldn't figure out from that if what I was trying to do was even possible. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems

I think you're just mixing up a couple of variables in your template. Just simplifying your template and better naming for variables will help you spot the errors. In particular:

`{% set myEntryQuery = craft.entries().section('nflTeams').all() %}`

This isn't used at all, what is it doing there? Get rid of unused code.

`{% set players = craft.entries.section('nflDraft2021').relatedTo(entry).all() %}`

You're calling the variable `players`, but your query returns `nflDraft2021` entries, this is causing confusion down the line.

`{% for player in players %}`

Same as above, your `player` variable is a `nflDraft2021` entry, not a `draftClass2021` entry. By the way, the `draftClass2021` is a really confusing name – the entries in the section represent players, not classes, right? Why not just name it `players` or `players2021`?

`{% set relatedEntries = player.draftPick.all() %}`

Now this is where you're actually getting the selected player, so **this**  variable should be called `player`. Also, if I understand your setup correctly each `nflDraft2021` entry only has one associated player, correct? In this case, you should make that clear in the code by using `.one()` to execute the query instead of `.all()`. This will give you the player entry (or null if none are selected) instead of an array, so you can get rid of the inner loop.

### Solutions

Not sure if you can get everything in one query – it should be possible using eager-loading. See [eager-loading nested elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-nested-sets-of-elements). However, you don't need to make it so complicated. I see two possible approaches:

1. Just use one query to get all `nflDraft2021` entries related to the current team, then iterate through those. Inside the loop, use another query to get the selected player for each draft and use eager-loading to load the school as well in one go.
2. Same as one, but after querying all `nflDraft2021` entries, use just one query to get ALL players related to those drafts (you can pass an array to `relatedTo`. Again, use eager-loading to include the schools as well. This alleviates the N+1 problem.

#### Approach #1 sample code

```
{# Get all draft entries for this team. #}
{% set draftEntries = craft.entries().section('nflDraft2021')
    .relatedTo(entry)
    .all()
%}

{# Iterate through the drafts for this team. #}
{% for draft in draftEntries %}
    {# Get the drafted player, preloading their school. #}
    {% set selectedPlayer = craft.entries().section('draftClass2021')
        .relatedTo(draft)
        .with(['playersSchool'])
        .one() %}
    {% set playerSchool = selectedPlayer.playersSchool[0] ?? null %}

    Slot: {{ draft.draftSlot }} <br>
    {% if selectedPlayer %}
        Player: {{ selectedPlayer.title }} <br>
        {% if playerSchool %}
            Player schook: {{ playerSchool.title }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Approach #2 sample code

```
{# Get all draft entries for this team. #}
{% set draftEntries = craft.entries().section('nflDraft2021')
    .relatedTo(entry)
    .all()
%}

{# Get all players selected by this team. #}
{% set selectedPlayers = craft.entries().section('draftClass2021')
    .relatedTo(draftEntries)
    .with(['playersSchool'])
    .all()
%}

{# Iterate through the players directly #}
{% for player in selectedPlayers %}
    {# Note the array access syntax to get the eager-loaded element. #}
    {% set playerSchool = player.playersSchool[0] ?? null %}

    Player: {{ player.title }} <br>
    {% if playerSchool %}
        Player school: {{ playerSchool.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I didn't know about eager-loading, and walking through where I had errors or inefficiencies is extremely helpful, so greatly appreciated. The first solution works perfectly for me, the second only returns the player names though.

Comment: @doctorgloom Glad I could help! I had some typos in the second example, should be correct now.

Comment: Another question, lets pretend the School Entries field allowed multiple selections (choosing multiple schools). How would you loop through that, listing all schools, with eager loading? When I try a for loop it just spits out the first item in the array multiple times. I can make it a new post if that's not clear.

Comment: @doctorgloom As far as I know, eager-loaded elements always end up in an array. In this case you'd loop over `player.playersSchool` instead of just accessing the first item. So instead of this: `player.playersSchool[0]`, you use a loop: `{% for school in player.playersSchool %} {{ school.title }} {% endfor %})`. If that's not working maybe post a new question, would have to see the code to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I thought the array was needed for the eager-loading.